# spring cloud config server deployment in multiple data centers

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, microservices

My applications run deployed to two data centers. What is the suggested deployment strategy for config server that enables HA and Disaster Recovery? I have the following choices and wondering how others are deploying/

**Option 1**

- Each data center has its own Git
- Each data center has a cluster of 2 config servers talking to the respective Git in that particular data center

**Option 2**

- One centralized Git across two data centers
- Each data center has a cluster of 2 config servers sourcing from the centralized Git repo

**Option 3**

- One centralized Git
- Config server cluster spans across data centers. i.e. One config server per data center

Comment: How available is your git server?

Comment: We can replicate git across datacenters

Comment: Config server is as available as you git server. Other than that I'd say at least two config servers per data center. It's also stateless.